# How to disable changing the current buffer by clicking buffer name in mode line?

Tags: buffers, mode-line, mouse

I find myself accidentally clicking the mode line when trying to focus a buffer with the mouse.  This causes the buffer to change.  I don't want that behavior.  I want nothing to happen.

The culprit is this guy here, the part of the mode line that says the buffer's name (e.g. `*shell*`):

[image]

How can I disable it's behavior when it clicked?

I am told it is `<down-mouse-1>` by `C-h k`.  However, this corresponds to `mouse-drag-mode-line` which resizes.  This is not the behavior I observe.  I cannot locate the appropriate key to override.

Comment: Good question. The mode-line is always difficult to ask Emacs about. Here, `C-h k` is not so useful.

Comment: It may have gotten better: when doing `C-h k` and clicking on the buffer name in the mode-line, I get a `*Help*` screen with two key sequences described: one is the `mouse-drag-mode-line` from `global-map` as above;  the other is `mode-line-previous-buffer` which  also identifies the `mode-line-buffer-identification-keymap` as described in @lawlist's answer. I'm on GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.13, cairo version 1.16.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```lisp
(define-key mode-line-buffer-identification-keymap [mode-line mouse-1] nil)

(define-key mode-line-buffer-identification-keymap [mode-line mouse-3] nil)
```

---

The variable `mode-line-buffer-identification-keymap` is defined within `bindings.el`.